# Creating a sharepoint site definition using onet.xml and site templates

Tags: 2010, site-template, provisioning

Im starting to develop a site definition using this tutorial http://vimeo.com/23670570 (which I found a good starting point. But lacks more detailed explanation). Everywhere I look in the onet.xml (copied from blog) I see declarations such as

```
Url="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,blogcatagories_Folder;"
```

My question is how do these resolve? Are these declared somewhere as constants? and how do I go about creating my own location in my project?

I hope I have explained myself clearly enough happy to provide more information if required.

ok thanks to @timetothine i can now definativley say that the $Resources part resolves to the resources folder ie on 2010

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\Resources
```

and the :core is the resx file ran in that folder. The only question mark that remains is the

,lists_Folder

and

blogcateagories_Folder;

where are these two defined?

Are they input params to the resx?

how do I define my own Folder?

Thanks in advance!

Nicholas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your confused with $Resources:core, You can access them from 12 hive, In my case they are all located in this folder location

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\Resources

This Link might help you

[Resorces in 12 hive](http://platinumdogs.me/2010/08/09/using-sharepoint-provisioning-and-application-resource-resx-files/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I see that the $resources equates to the resources folder and I guess core refers  to the core.resx file that resides in that folder. But what about the next part specifically blogcatagories_Folder; part. How do I go about creating this. Thanks Nicholas

Comment: If you open Core.resx file yu will find a string with name "blogcatagories_Folder"

Comment: Fantastic, I can see that now. Thank you very much for all your help :-)